# Solver set priority for specific constraints

Tags: excel, solver, coin-or-cbc

I try to solve large optimization problem in Excel using OpenSolver.

Problem is that I have two sets of constraints:

- "MUST" constraints ('=' rows in picture)
- "NICE TO HAVE" constraints ('>=' rows in picture): I do not mind that much if those are violated

When I solve "MUST" constraints alone I can easily get optimal solution however when I add 'nice to have' to the model in result I get some of them violated (both, 'must' and also 'nice to have')

I need to somehow tell the solver that first set of rules are absolute priority and second might be violated.

(softer rules are not solution unfortunately)

[image]

Comment: First why not set constraints as an array such as: $J$106:$J$119>=$L$106:$L$119. Then try perhaps gradually adding the nice constraints until it fails to find the infeasible boundaries.

Comment: I know about array, I just add it programmatically and it might not be ordered by sign. Do you think it has also performance aspect aside from esthetical? I was thinking about gradual adding too, but problem is pretty big (few mins to solve).

Comment: So, add 1/2 the nice constraints and then 1/4 or 3/4 depending on the first result - that puts you in the ball park. Unless it is a particular "nice" constraint that is more serious...

Comment: "nice to have constraints" are called "soft constraints" or "elastic constraints". They are modeled by adding slacks to the constraints (making them = constraints) and then adding penalty terms to the objective containing these slack variables.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, that helped me a lot. I will accept if you add answer.